# How to include Yacc/Bison-Parser into own project?

Tags: c, eclipse, parsing, makefile, bison

I'd like to use the yacc/bison parser for my own project. 
When building the Parser with my own Makefile, everything works fine. I took the sources from  http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/kconfig-frontends (just the parser that's: `/<path-to-kconfig>/libs/parser`.

Now when including these files into the C++ project in Eclipse, after hitting make, the compiler crashes at the `.y` file, because of a syntax error - wasn't able to read the .y - syntax. So I excluded the parser from the building process.

In the answer of [Yacc and Lex inclusion confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486106/yacc-and-lex-inclusion-confusion), I've read that only the .h files have to be included, to use the functions of the parser.

**So what I did is:**

- To get access to the parser sources out of *my* project, I created a simple function that just prints a line on the console in yconf.y and yconf.c: `void testout(char *txt) {printf(txt);}`
- I even created a yconf.h with the function-head `void testout(char *txt);`
- compiled the parser with my own makefile
- the main, where I'd like to call the function looks like:

  ```
  #include "y.tab.h"
  #include "yconf.h"
  #include <stdio.h>

  extern "C"{
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      char configIn[] = "test";
      printf(configIn);

      testout(configIn);

      return 0;
  }
  }
  ```

**The error**

And now when compiling, an error appears: `undefined reference to 'testout(char*)'`. But Eclipse itself can resolve the function - when clicking that function, the yconf.h opens. And that's why I don't know where exactly the problem is.

**Eclipse Settings:**

In /project/properties/C/C++ Build/Settings I put the same include paths to the parser-sources for `gcc` and `g++` and the linker. Additionally I added in this settings as "Include files" the `y.tab.h` and the `yconf.h`

If more information are needed, please ask.

I appreciate any advises about how to solve this problem. Thanks for the support

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay one really just need the `y.tab.h` and `y.tab.c`. That is created with this makefile:

```
lex ./lconf.l
bison -d -y ./yconf.y
```

My error was: I was programming in C++ and I had the `extern "C"` command at the wrong place, that header file needs to be *declared* as c format. Here's the right code:

```
extern "C"{
    #include "y.tab.h"
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char configIn[] = "test";  
    testout(configIn);
    return 0;
}
```

(testout is a function in y.tab.h/c with a simple `printf` of the parameter configIn - when executing "test" was printed.)

BTW: I excluded all source files of the parser for compilation but of the `y.tab.c`